# The following FormatException was thrown building Builder(dirty): FormatException in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, input, formatexception

i am building a timer app. the homepage will be a setting page. then from the setting page I will create a button and navigate to inputdatacountdown page. this page is basically import number by the user. then the data will be past to the countdowntimer page. there will be duration and I will past to it. the problem here is I don't know why flutter tell me format exception. this is the error I got

```
The following FormatException was thrown building Builder(dirty):
FormatException

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp file:///C:/Users/gary%20gan/AndroidStudioProjects/myfirstflipclock_createown/lib/main.dart:11:5
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/errors.dart 236:49  throw_
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 178:5             parse
packages/myfirstflipclock_createown/settingpage.dart 39:63                                                                 <fn>
packages/flutter/src/material/page.dart 53:55                                                                              buildContent
packages/flutter/src/material/page.dart 106:27                                                                             buildPage
...
====================================================================================================
```

this is my setting page code

```
class Settingpage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  //search for how to use if else in flutter by giving the terms
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('settingscreen'),
      ),
      body: Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: Text('go back home')),
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DateTimePicker()),
                    );
                    },
                    child: Text('set your time and date'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24.0,),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => inputdatacountdown()),
                    );
                    },
                    child: Text('count down timer'),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 24.0,),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ])),
    );
  }
}
```

this is my inputdatapage and also countdowntimerpage

```
class inputdatacountdown extends StatefulWidget {
  var hourController = TextEditingController();
  int inputdata;
  inputdatacountdown(){
    inputdata=int.parse(hourController.text);
  }
  @override
  _inputdatacountdownState createState() => _inputdatacountdownState();
}

class _inputdatacountdownState extends State<inputdatacountdown> {
  int inputdata;
  _inputdatacountdownState(){
    inputdata=int.parse(hourController.text);
  }
  var hourController = TextEditingController();
  final minuteController = TextEditingController();
  final secondController = TextEditingController();
  final _key = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final nametext =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.white
        : Colors.black;
    final nametextonbutton =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.black
        : Colors.white;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: Form(
              key: _key,
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: hourController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'hours',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              hourController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'hours cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: minuteController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'minutes',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              minuteController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'minutes cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  TextFormField(
                      controller: secondController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: 'e.g 1',
                        labelText: 'second',
                        border:
                        OutlineInputBorder(),
                        suffixIcon: IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
                          onPressed: () =>
                              secondController
                                  .clear(),
                        ),
                      ),
                      keyboardType:
                      TextInputType.number,
                      textInputAction:
                      TextInputAction.done,
                      validator: (value) {
                        if (value.isEmpty) {
                          return 'second cannot be empty';
                        } else
                          return null;
                      }),
                  FlatButton(
                      color: nametext,
                      onPressed: () {
                        if (_key.currentState
                            .validate()) {
                          print(
                              'hour: ${hourController.text}');
                          print(
                              'minutes: ${minuteController.text}');
                          print(
                              'second: ${secondController.text}');
                          _sumbitok();
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>CountDownTimer( inputdataint: inputdata)));
                        }
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'submit ',
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color:
                            nametextonbutton),
                      ))
                ],
              )),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  void _sumbitok() {
    Widget okbutton = FlatButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
      child: Text('ok'),
    );

    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Dialog title'),
      content: Text("you have already submit the number"),
      actions: [
        okbutton,
      ],
    );

    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }
}

class CountDownTimer extends StatefulWidget {
  int inputdataint;
  CountDownTimer({Key key,@required this.inputdataint}):super(key:key);
  @override
  _CountDownTimerState createState() => _CountDownTimerState();//inputdataint:
}

class _CountDownTimerState extends State<CountDownTimer>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int inputdataint;
  _CountDownTimerState({this.inputdataint});
  AnimationController controller;

  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: inputdataint),//come back to you later
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    final nametext =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.white
        : Colors.black;
    final nametextonbutton =
    MediaQuery.of(context).platformBrightness == Brightness.dark
        ? Colors.black
        : Colors.white;



    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white10,
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                        animation: controller,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                        color: themeData.indicatorColor,
                                      )),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                    MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Count Down Timer",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0, color: nametext),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        timerString,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 112.0, color: nametext),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: controller,
                          builder: (context, child) {
                            return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  if (controller.isAnimating)
                                    controller.stop();
                                  else {
                                    controller.reverse(
                                        from: controller.value == 0.0
                                            ? 1.0
                                            : controller.value);
                                  }
                                },
                                icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow),
                                label: Text(
                                    controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Play"));
                          }),
                    ],
                  ))
            ]);
          }),
    );
  }


}
```

thank you for your time and for your help.

Comment: The error comes from `main.dart`, could you add the code of this file?

Answer (score 1):

In the following code you are defining hourController which by default its text is empty and then in the constructor you are parsing/converting that empty value into int which is the cause of your problem.
And you did that in the state class too.

```
  var hourController = TextEditingController();
  int inputdata;
  inputdatacountdown(){
   inputdata=int.parse(hourController.text);
 }
```

To solve this you can give default value to hourController

e.g

```
var hourController = TextEditingController(text: '1');
```